# Resetting a countdown to date timer to another date when it ends

Tags: c#, datetime, countdown, timespan

Ok so what I want to do is when then countdowns ends which means reach the endTime I've put this in 2 days, I want to reset and add another 7 days and keep doing that if possible. I've tried using

```
if(endTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now) = 0)
        {

        }
```

but that gives me an error "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer" and also converting ts to a string using .ToString() method but that still did not work! all code is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146602/creating-countdown-to-date-c-sharp) I wanted to comment there but I am a new user. Thanks in advance I think I covered it all ask for anything before downvoting please!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TV_Series_New_Episodes
{
public partial class Flash : Form
{
    DateTime endTime = new DateTime(2015, 11 ,19, 14 ,30, 0);

    public Flash()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ct_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = endTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        ctlb.Text = ts.ToString("d' Days 'h' Hours 'm' Minutes 's' Seconds'");
        if(endTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now) = 0)
        {

        }
    }

    private void Flash_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        ct.Interval= 500;
        ct.Tick += new EventHandler(ct_Tick);
        TimeSpan ts = endTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        ctlb.Text = ts.ToString("d' Days 'h' Hours 'm' Minutes 's' Seconds'");
        ct.Start();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

`=` is the assignment operator. If you want to compare, use `==`.

You cannot compare a `TimeSpan` with an `ìnt`. Use the `TimeSpan`'s `TotalDays` properties to get a number. Or just use the arguments directly.

Finally, your program might not hit the `endTime` exactly. So you should allow some tolerance:

```
if(endTime <= DateTime.Now)
{

}
```

Comment: DateTime has no TotalDays property TimeSpan does if that's what you meant and I still need some guidance , what should I replace the if I mentioned I tried using ts.TotalDays == endTime but it won'tt accept the operator.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Just use the `if(endTime <= DateTime.Now)` or if you really want `if(endTime == DateTime.Now)`.

Comment: Falcon, TotalDays is just a double, which cannot be compared to a DateTime.  If you truly want endTime to equal DateTime.Now (down to the millisecond) you need to do if (endTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds == 0).  If you really care about endTime being any time after Now, just do what Nico suggested if (endTime < DateTime.Now)

Comment: @NicoSchertler I am quite dumb.... `if(endtime<= DateTime.Now)` worked perfectly, thank you very much for your help and your tolerance!

Comment: @NicoSchertler Oh one more matter I forgot about, I have assigned some values for the date `(2015, 11 ,19, 14 ,30, 0)` how can I edit inside the `if(endTime <= DateTime.Now)` ?

Comment: In C#, `DateTime` is immutable, i.e. you cannot modify it. So you have to assign a new `DateTime` instance to the variable: `endTime = endTime.AddDays(7)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Nico's answer, `endTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now)` returns a `TimeSpan` object (not `DateTime`) which has the TotalTimeUnit properties.